# Background image doesn't show when defined in stylesheet

Tags: css, background

I am very new to css so this maybe a simple answer.  I have 2 scenarios and 1 works the other doesn't.  I hope someone can help me out.

WORKS:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
body { 
    background-image:url('views/default/images/home.jpg');
;}
</style>
</head>
```

DOESN'T WORK:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="views/default/home_style.css" />
</head>
```

In home_style.css>

```
body{ 
    background-image:url('views/default/images/home.jpg');
    margin-top: 0px !important; 
    padding-top: 0px !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like your CSS file is in the `views/default/` folder, while the image is in the `views/default/images/` folder.

Define image paths in your CSS relative to the *CSS file*, not the HTML file that displays everything:

```
background-image:url('images/home.jpg');
```

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, the source doesn't have to be in quotes; you could save exactly two characters by doing `url(images/home.jpg)`

Comment: I did the exact same thing. but it only work on my debug environment. When I publish to azure, it doesn't work. any idea why?

Answer (score 5):

**In my case:**

I had a **CSS** folder.  So, inside my **CSS** folder I had my `style.css` so I was typing inside my `style.css` the following:

`background: url('img/mybgimg.jpg')`

instead of

`background: url('../img/mybgimg.jpg')`

...I hope this can help to anyone who is having the same issue.