# Custom underline for a menu on hover and focus

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to use [this](https://www.dropbox.com) image as the underline for menu items on hover and focus (or when active). I have tried a lot of things but the image will not show up no matter what. Normal text-decoration underlines work fine. I am using the blankstate theme. Any suggestions and ideas will be greatly appreciated. The image is in the same folder as the custom css I want to use. You can check out the sample site [here](https://#). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064965/background-image-doesnt-show-when-defined-in-styesheet) question's answer doesn't apply here I guess. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567860/css-background-image-doesnt-display). By the way, I am assuming that the

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path_to_css" />
```

is taken care of automatically by the theme, if not, how can I access the header file to ensure that it is done. I am using elementor to edit the page.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I would love it if someone would explain the down vote after they down vote. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to setup background-size property. after that take care of its position

for example, background-size: 100%

Comment: but was it you that downvoted the question, if so, could you explain why?

Comment: No, it wasn't me.

Comment: oh alright, I just don't want to make the same mistake again. thats why :)

Comment: Try to make a clear question next time to avoid a downvote by anyone who is surprised by a complex question from a simple problem. Just explain your problem and at the end explain what resources you've used to get there. For example the code you've posted isn't important for your question...

Comment: oh thank you Fabian. But I thought as I was using wordpress, it would be necessary to make it clear. Since I am not the one to explicitly write that statement in wordpress. it's the template.

Answer (score 3):

Try this css:

```css
a:hover, a:hover, a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/bYYfllb.png');
    background-size: 100% 18px; /* stretch to link width but keep its height */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* do not repeat the image */
    background-position: bottom;
    padding-bottom: 8px; /* move image below the text */
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
Test <a href="#">link</a> and <a href="#">with a longer link text</a>
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but as @Georgiy Dubrov answered first, I guess I have to accept his first. But I will definitely upvote this for the insight given. Also, only the y-position I found that I had to define the y position only and in percentages for it to work fine.

Comment: @guthik if this answer is better for you, mark it as solution. For me it's not a problem who was first.

Comment: choose what answered your question & plz no regrets :)

Comment: ok, this is a tough one now. My original problem was to show the image. declaring the size (Georgiy) did the trick. But Fabian helped alot with the placement and understanding of the code. So I will just stick to the first choice for now. thanks alot though. Now I will struggle with making the underline the same width for all the elements and placing the words at the center of the underline. Even if I need to add extra spaces.